# Does Pantheon-Mail allow download options

Tags: pantheon-mail

Does the Pantheon-mail program have the ability to download NO ATTACHMENTS and to say how many days to download (like the user friendly gmail android app does)?

If so let me know.  I will set it up. I am afraid to otherwise and there is no information on this. For some reason, in my past experience, only thunderbird allows this and it does not do a good job either.  Geary had no options and wanted me to pay for some (I am a monk).  I gave up (so far) and use the web for desktop mail and my phone to see offline stuff.
It seems very intuitive and Pantheon email would have an interface that mimics the easy to use, we researched gmail app, which is sort of the goal (I hope).